# Arbitrary 2D random number generation based on single seed

Tags: random, procedural-generation

I am trying to fully cover a 2D space with random values based on a seed and starting at an origin, from which i want to be able to go into all directions without much computation.

The basic idea is that i need a function `float rnd_2d(int x, int y, uint64_t seed);` that generates a random number based on the inputs in O(1).

My goal is to create noise procedurally in all directions.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton In fact yes, but perlin noise is based off of width and height of the target area, yet i don't have that defined, theoretically being infinite, leading to too much computational requirements.

Comment: Perlin noise is often a good fit for this kind of thing, but one of the problems is that the noise has a bell curve distribution, ie there are more values near 0.5 than near 0 or 1.0. This is fine for some things but definitely not for others.